# JQuery code to work only on one width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating responsive navigation bar with a hamburger menu and i have a problem.

When I resize the window on 700px width and refresh page it is working fine, but
when I refresh page on full size screen and then resize code isn't working.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        if($(window).width() < 700){
                $(".topnav").hide();
                $(".icon").click(function(){
                    $(".topnav").slideToggle();
                });
            }
    });
```

When I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `document ready` and `window resize` are two different event,you need to add same code in `$(window).resize(function(){..});` too

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  checkWindowWidth();
});

$(window).resize(function(){
  checkWindowWidth();
});

function checkWindowWidth(){
  if($(window).width() < 700){
      $(".topnav").hide();
      $(".icon").click(function(){
      $(".topnav").slideToggle();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Now sometimes SlideToggle works automatically also when I turn off menu on clicking hamburger and when i resize on full screen again i don't see anything. Thanks for Help guys.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to bind the function to resize event, instead of load event, otherwise it only trigger once at the beginning:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).trigger('resize');
});

$(window).on('resize', function(){
    if($(window).width() < 700){
        $(".topnav").hide();
        $(".icon").click(function(){
             $(".topnav").slideToggle();
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You code above is only written to run when the document is loaded -- that's what `$(document).ready` is all about -- so it's not surprising that nothing happens when you resize the window after that document is loaded.

What you need is:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", resizeLogicGoesHere);
```

Plus you've only written code to go from big to small. You should add code to trigger a change if the user goes from a small screen size up to a larger one too.